# Are tattoos haram?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

I have heard that tattoos are haram by a lot of people. I am not looking to get a tattoo, but I was curious though why they are prohibited. I have not seen any text to support this thought. If anyone could provide any insight into this issue it would be very much appreciated. If there is any text, I would like to see the original Arabic text as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tattoos are haraam because they are a disfiguring of the body that Allah has given us. The body we have is a trust from Allah and should be looked after. Tattoos disfigure the body and change in the way that Allah has created us.

Rasoolullah (saw) cursed the tattooer and one who is tattooed..." - Muslim.

Answer (score -1):

If it's healthy and clean, it's allowed. Look 5:87, 7:32, 66:1. Determining whether it's healthy or not is not a religious subject. It's a scientific one. Do your scientific or medical research.